# Turn on/off button for a script/function in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a grade calculator extension. I am trying to make a checkbox turn on/off button for my extensition. By default it remain off and when turn on it should remain turn on untill i manually press the button again to turn off. When i turn on it does't get turn on and when the popup page goes dispear  it turn off. basically i am trying to run a script/ function when the button is turn on and not when it off. I am not trying to implement extension turn on/off button. i just want to run a script or function.

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Uni Grade Calulate</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="wrapper-center">
        <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" id="toggleSwitch" checked />
          <div class="switch--toggle"></div>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

content1.js:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('toggleState', function(data) {
  const toggleSwitch = document.getElementById('toggleSwitch');
  toggleSwitch.checked = data.toggleState || false;
  updateExtensionState(toggleSwitch.checked);
});

document.getElementById('toggleSwitch').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  const toggleState = event.target.checked;
  updateExtensionState(toggleState);
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ 'toggleState': toggleState });
});

function updateExtensionState(enabled) {
  if (enabled) {

    alert('Extension is enabled');
  } else {
    
    alert('Extension is disabled');
  }
}
```

manifest.json:

```
{
   "manifest_version": 3,
   "name": "UCP Grade Calculate",
   "version": "1.0.1",
   "description": "Uni Grade Calculate is an extension to calculate the grades of any course.",
   "icons": {
     "128": "icons/gradeblue128.png",
     "16": "icons/gradeblue16.png",
     "48": "icons/gradeblue48.png"
   },
   "action": {
     "default_popup": "popup.html",
     "default_title": "UCP Grade Calculate"
   },
   "content_scripts": [
     {
       "matches": [
         "https://uniwebsite.com/*"
       ],
       "js": [
         "content1.js"
       ]
     }
   ],
   "permissions": [
     "storage",
     "tabs"
   ]
 }
```

I tried search the web use chatgpt but did'nt get the right method to solve this problem.

Comment: Instead of `content_scripts` use chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts and unregisterContentScripts to toggle content.js inside updateExtensionState.